# pushNavigationController on iOS 5 messed up my UINavigationBar when I pop back to the previous view controller

Tags: iphone

My main view controller only supports landscapeleft and landscaperight.  This viewcontroller in the viewDidLoad has:

```
if ([self.navigationItem respondsToSelector:@selector(leftItemsSupplementBackButton)]) {
    self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = homeBBI;

    NSArray *rightNavItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchBBI, allBBI, nil];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = rightNavItems;
}
```

When I push my ReportViewController onto the stack, it looks fine.  This controller also supports landscape only.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

When I rotate the iPad 180 degrees, all looks fine.  However when I pop to the main view controller, the UINavigationBar gets messed up.  It basically has all the items, including the title squished to the left.  The search bar I had ends up taking up 75% of the navigation bar.  I created it like this in viewDidLoad of my MainViewController:

```
// Search Bar
    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 44)];
    self.SearchEntry = searchBar;
    self.SearchEntry.delegate = self;
    UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayCtlr = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchEntry contentsController:self];
    self.SearchController = searchDisplayCtlr;
    searchDisplayCtlr.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    searchDisplayCtlr.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    UIBarButtonItem *searchBBI = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_searchEntry];
```

This does not happen in iOS 4 since I create a UIToolBar and put that as my rightBarButtonItem.  Now that I'm trying to use the rightBarButtonItems iOS 5 method, I get this problem.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Edit: This also does not happen if i pop to my MainVC without rotating the iPad.  It only happens if I rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set autoresizing masks so that the toolbar knows to resize? I imagine so if it rotates fine without the other MVC on top.

I have had similar issues with this, in particular ensuring my main VC rotates correctly when it isn't on screen. I'm not sure if my solution is great, but it works. When returning from another view, I check if my bounds changed and if so, clear my view (enumerate subviews and removeFromSuperview), then load them all again. Basically, keep everything you have in viewDidLoad in another method and call it from viewWillAppear. The drawing is super fast so you won't even notice it on screen.

Not elegant, so I'll be watching to see if anyone has a better solution.

Good luck,

Damien

Comment: Yeah I'm looking into it.  I'll check the resizing masks since I don't set those.  It's weird though, b/c the tool bar changes its color as well.  I don't set the color, I just set the size, but it matches the UINavigationBar with a black background.  Then after I rotate it turns to the default white color and gets HUGE.

Comment: Are you using IB? I have played around with the Inferred settings for the NavigationController and subsequent child controllers, and the results can be "interesting." I leave that kind of color/font polish until the end though, no use spending a bunch of time when you might scrap the entire view at some point. Have fun.